# Prove a curve is asymptotic

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove that the curve $x=\frac{2}{1+t},y=\frac{2}{1-t}, z=t $ is an asymptotic
curve on the surface $z=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}$.

I calculated $f_x=\frac{-2}{x^3},f_y=\frac{2}{y^3}, f_{xx}=\frac{6}{x^4}, f_{xy}=0, f_{yy}=\frac{-6}{y^4}$ and then $L=\frac{6}{x^4\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^6}+\frac{4}{y^6}}}, N=0, M=\frac{-6}{y^4\sqrt{1+\frac{4}{x^6}+\frac{4}{y^6}}}$.

From there I tried to use the formula $L(\frac{du}{dt})^2+2M(\frac{du}{dt})(\frac{dv}{dt})+N(\frac{dv}{dt})^2=0$ but ran into trouble. How am I supposed to calculate $(\frac{du}{dt})$ or $(\frac{dv}{dt})$ when I wasn't given a function u or v? I know u and v are both functions of t, but I'm still not sure what I'm supposed to be deriving.

Answer (score 0):

$u$ and $v$ are the two variables in terms of which you parametrize your surface. In your case, they're $x$ and $y$. But you need to be computing derivatives of the vector parametrization $\vec r(u,v)$, which is in this case $\vec r(x,y) = (x,y,x^{-2}-y^{-2})$. I guess you actually did that, even though it's not evident. However, you typed $M$ where you should have had $N$, and vice versa. At any rate, it's going to be easy to see (once you straighten that out and take $du/dt=dx/dt$ and $dv/dt=dy/dt$) that the curve in fact satisfies the equation you gave.